# How to solve Docker Buildx Error on M1 Pro?

Tags: docker, rust, x86-64, apple-m1, arm64

I was trying to build a Docker image for a Rust "helloworld" webapp in a Docker Multi platform image.
However, my build for the `linux/amd64` image always fail while the `linux/arm64` build always succeed.

My config:

- MacBook Pro 2021 M1 Pro 32GB RAM
- MacOS 12.4
- Docker for Desktop 4.10.1

My `src/main.rs` is:

```
use actix_web::{get, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

#[get("/hello_world")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(hello))
        .bind(("0.0.0.0", 5000))?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

and my `cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "helloworld"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
tokio = { version = "1.19.2", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }


[profile.release]
codegen-units=1
```

and my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rust:latest as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt update && apt install lld clang -y
RUN cargo clean && cargo update
RUN cargo build --release --bin helloworld



FROM debian:bullseye-slim AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl ca-certificates \
    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && apt-get install -y bash \
    # Clean up
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/helloworld helloworld
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./helloworld"]
```

Then I run `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t helloword plain .`  and got the following error:

```
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x4e54e3)[0x40021864e3]
#25 30.77 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14140)[0x4005fbf140]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZNK4llvm13AttributeList19addAttributeAtIndexERNS_11LLVMContextEjNS_9Attribute8AttrKindE+0xb10)[0x40089725b0]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm26PostOrderFunctionAttrsPass3runERNS_13LazyCallGraph3SCCERNS_15AnalysisManagerIS2_JRS1_EEES5_RNS_17CGSCCUpdateResultE+0x37e)[0x40089edc6e]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(+0x284e8dd)[0x40089ed8dd]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm11PassManagerINS_13LazyCallGraph3SCCENS_15AnalysisManagerIS2_JRS1_EEEJS4_RNS_17CGSCCUpdateResultEEE3runERS2_RS5_S4_S7_+0x482)[0x4008efb052]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(+0x2d5bbbd)[0x4008efabbd]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm21DevirtSCCRepeatedPass3runERNS_13LazyCallGraph3SCCERNS_15AnalysisManagerIS2_JRS1_EEES5_RNS_17CGSCCUpdateResultE+0x23a)[0x4008f461ea]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(+0x2da6f9d)[0x4008f45f9d]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm33ModuleToPostOrderCGSCCPassAdaptor3runERNS_6ModuleERNS_15AnalysisManagerIS1_JEEE+0x107b)[0x4008d05bdb]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(+0x2b65b4d)[0x4008d04b4d]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm11PassManagerINS_6ModuleENS_15AnalysisManagerIS1_JEEEJEE3runERS1_RS3_+0x144)[0x40092d8274]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm24ModuleInlinerWrapperPass3runERNS_6ModuleERNS_15AnalysisManagerIS1_JEEE+0x185)[0x40092d7905]
#25 30.77 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(+0x313876d)[0x40092d776d]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm11PassManagerINS_6ModuleENS_15AnalysisManagerIS1_JEEEJEE3runERS1_RS3_+0x144)[0x40092d8274]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x2638b01)[0x40042d9b01]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x262fb98)[0x40042d0b98]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x26300be)[0x40042d10be]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x2625cad)[0x40042c6cad]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x25f553f)[0x400429653f]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x2617e93)[0x40042b8e93]
#25 30.78 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/libstd-69edc9ac8de4d39c.so(rust_metadata_std_8996aeeb2a45fe64+0xab3c3)[0x4005ccb3c3]
#25 30.78 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8ea7)[0x4005fb3ea7]
#25 30.78 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x40060d5def]
#25 30.78 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#25 30.80 error: could not compile `bytes`
#25 30.80 
#25 30.80 Caused by:
#25 30.80   process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name bytes --edition=2018 /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bytes-1.2.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C codegen-units=1 --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=6da28169ce33971a -C extra-filename=-6da28169ce33971a --out-dir /app/target/release/deps -L dependency=/app/target/release/deps --cap-lints allow` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)
#25 30.80 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
#25 33.26 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x4e54e3)[0x40021864e3]
#25 33.27 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14140)[0x4005fbf140]
#25 33.27 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc(+0x48941)[0x4000048941]
#25 33.27 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc(+0x9841)[0x4000009841]
#25 33.27 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm9MCContext5resetEv+0x55c)[0x400935c49c]
#25 33.27 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm28MachineModuleInfoWrapperPass14doFinalizationERNS_6ModuleE+0x35)[0x400935bf05]
#25 33.27 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/../lib/libLLVM-14-rust-1.62.1-stable.so(_ZN4llvm6legacy15PassManagerImpl3runERNS_6ModuleE+0xb0)[0x4009442660]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x2634c75)[0x40042d5c75]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x262ddb7)[0x40042cedb7]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x26310c6)[0x40042d20c6]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x262be78)[0x40042cce78]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x2625d43)[0x40042c6d43]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x25f553f)[0x400429653f]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/librustc_driver-1bde28880ea8bde8.so(+0x2617e93)[0x40042b8e93]
#25 33.28 /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/libstd-69edc9ac8de4d39c.so(rust_metadata_std_8996aeeb2a45fe64+0xab3c3)[0x4005ccb3c3]
#25 33.28 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8ea7)[0x4005fb3ea7]
#25 33.28 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x40060d5def]
#25 33.28 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#25 33.29 error: could not compile `typenum`
#25 33.29 
#25 33.29 Caused by:
#25 33.29   process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_main --edition=2018 /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/typenum-1.15.0/build/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=ee6956477f56ac1c -C extra-filename=-ee6956477f56ac1c --out-dir /app/target/release/build/typenum-ee6956477f56ac1c -L dependency=/app/target/release/deps --cap-lints allow` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)
```

I am stuck on it for 3 days now, do you know where it might come from and how to solve it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Am I correct in assuming `RUN cargo build --release --bin helloworld` is the layer that fails?

Comment: Yes that's the the layer that fails

Comment: I was able to reproduce on M1. Interesting... Though cross building is far from a trivial, *should just work* concern. Some things just don't and you can't really expect them to. Since x86_64 cloud costs are cheap, I'd quick fix that by building natively, if possible. Probably not worth pursuing this, could be a problem deep down in the 'bytes' crate.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent yeah that's strange! I am on an early stage of a startup project, so I did not decide yet which cloud host to use. Sure it would be the good solution at the end!  I am compiling on my Linux computer instead now :p

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your Dockerfile per environment. So, locally, you will declare a linux arm64 for running on your M1, and if you need amd64 on your server, have that in your server's Dockerfile instead.
Like this at the top of your file, as an example:

```
FROM --platform=arm64 node:18-alpine as base
FROM base AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

...
```