# error while loading shared libraries: libstd-69edc9ac8de4d39c.so

Tags: docker, rust, carbon-lang

I am building a docker container for compiling a mix of rust, carbon and c.
Everything seems to work until running main.carbon and call the function of my rust library. Although the import seems valid. I think that is an issue by Rust code.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
#
#  --------   ----------   -----
#  | rust |   | carbon |   | C |
#  --------   ----------   -----
#      |           |         |
#      |           |         |
FROM rust as rust
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY ./src/lib/ .
RUN cargo build --verbose --release --all-targets --manifest-path /usr/src/myapp/Cargo.toml
#                  |         |
# install carbon   |         |
#            ------|         |
#            |     |         |
FROM linuxbrew/brew as brew
RUN brew update
RUN brew install python@3.9
RUN brew install bazelisk
RUN brew install llvm
#                  |         |
#                  |         |
#                  |         |
#                  |         |
FROM brew as carbon
RUN git clone https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang carbon
WORKDIR /home/linuxbrew/carbon
COPY --from=rust /usr/src/myapp/target/release/librust_file_listener.so /home/linuxbrew/carbon/explorer/
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN mv -v /home/linuxbrew/carbon/explorer/BUILD /home/linuxbrew/carbon/explorer/ BUILD-old
RUN touch ./explorer/BUILD
RUN echo $(pwd)
RUN sed -n '1,17p' ./explorer/BUILD-old >> ./explorer/BUILD
RUN echo '    srcs = ["main.cpp", "librust_file_listener.so"],' >> ./explorer/BUILD
RUN sed -n '19,$p' ./explorer/BUILD-old >> ./explorer/BUILD
RUN cp ./explorer/librust_file_listener.so .
RUN bazel build --verbose_failures //explorer
COPY ./src/main.carbon .
COPY ./src/file-listener.h .
RUN bazel run //explorer -- ./main.carbon
```

This is my error message:

```
/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/c2431547aff5b972703b3babc3d841cc/execroot/carbon/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/explorer/explorer: 
    error while loading shared libraries: libstd-69edc9ac8de4d39c.so: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Searching for this error message: the only result was this [question by laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063937/how-to-solve-docker-buildx-error-on-m1-pro). May be corresponding!?

FYI I am on x86_64, not on ARM.

Comment: I can't help with Carbon, but `RUN cp ./explorer/librust_file_listener.so` says that's the library filename you *intend* to load, but your error message has a different filename, so I would guess that the import/linking from Carbon is going wrong.

Comment: the import itself is working, i tried renaming the library the the import wont work anymore: `missing input file '//explorer:librust_file_listener.so'`, so either carbon doesn't support .so libs (yet) or the issue is on rust's side